# Why cant i change directory on desktop in terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal

When i want to change the directory to a specific folder on my desktop (summer 2020 classes) it tells me that no such user or named directory exists.

I want to open 'summer 2020 classes' from desktop

Example from terminal:

```
cd desktop 
cd summer 2020 classes
```

and i get this error:

```
string not in pwd: summer  
or 
too many arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the `cd` command thinks you are giving it three different directories (summer, 2020 and classes) when it expects a single one.

For files and directories containing spaces you need to either enclose in quotes or escape the spaces:

```
cd "summer 2020 classes"   # using quotes
```

or

```
cd summer\ 2020\ classes   # escaping the spaces
```

Answer (score -1):

Type cd c:\ . Now press the tab key (this is auto-complete, which will save you a lot of typing) repeatedly until it shows you a directory with spaces in the name. Notice how it delimits the path with apostrophes '. Use the same character when you're typing.

Edit: Make sure to use an apostrophe, not a backtick.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'd suggest you delete this answer.  While this works in Windows environment, the question is about Mac OS, which has no drive letters. Command 'cd c:\' is invalid.